# How I can get many html forms from a single page, in one flask function

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/profile<int:id>',methods=['POST','GET'])
def profile(id):
      id13=session['id']
      id_profile=id
      search=None
      row=None
      if id13 != id_profile:
            return redirect(url_for('logout'))
      if id13 == "" :
            return redirect(url_for('logout'))

      if request.method=="POST":
            search2=request.form['search']        
            sql="SELECT * FROM muzeu WHERE name LIKE '%"+search2+"%' "
            con.execute(sql)
            search=con.fetchall()
      if request.method=="POST":
            insert1=request.form["insert1"]
            insert2=request.form["insert2"]
            sql2="INSERT INTO comments VALUES('','"+insert1+"','"+insert2+"')"
            con.execute(sql2)

      sql3="SELECT * FROM comments "
      con.execute(sql3)
      row=con.fetchall()  
      return render_template("profile.html",search=search,row=row)           


and my html page forms

<form method="POST" action="">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit1">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


<form method="POST">
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Nume</span>
    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="insert1" placeholder="Additional Info">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Descriere</span>
    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="insert2" placeholder="Additional Info">
  </div>
 <input type="submit" name="submit2" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">
</form>
```

I try to learn flask and I can't get the answear on this question .
I try to make an profile page with  a search ,an insert and dispaying the insert.

After submition i get http error 400 bad request
"The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one form can be submitted by the browser. You're trying to process the data from both, but the non-submitted data won't exist in `request.form` and will raise a 400 error.

You need to be able to distinguish which form was submitted. Add a name and value to the submit button and check which value was returned to know what processing to do. You were on the right track by adding buttons with names, but you weren't consistent about them and weren't checking their value in Flask.

```html
<!-- in the search form -->
<button type=submit name=action value=search>

<!-- in the second form -->
<button type=submit name=action value=comment>
```

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['action'] == 'search':
        # do search action
    elif request.form['action'] == 'comment':
        # do comment action
```

---

In this case, it makes more sense to have different views handling searching and commenting. Create two separate views, and point the forms at the correct URLs.

```html
<form method=post action="{{ url_for('search') }}">

<form method=post action="{{ url_for('comment') }}">
```